# Crypto from nodeJs to Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular

How can I install crypto from nodeJs and how to use it in Angular2?
Is there some dependencies to inject in my project?
(http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

Comment: Why not just make a full-stack JS app with an Angular2 front-end and Node w/ Crypto backend?

Answer (score 1):

You can't take any node module and expect it to operate in the browser environment. Some modules work in both environments but `crypto` is **not** one of those modules.

Maybe you should look into [window.crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto) for browser-based cryptography